# The default value is displayed as empty in "select"

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set the default value of a select tag containing objects in a form, but for some reason it is always displayed empty.

```
<label for="favcity">
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.priorityareas_id" id="favcity" name="select" #priorityareas_id='ngModel'>
    <option *ngFor="let Priorityarea of Priorityareas" [ngValue]="Priorityarea.priorityarea_id">
     {{Priorityarea.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</label>
```

I also tried to use [value], but useless, it's still an empty default value.

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz

Comment: Maybe selectedUser.priorityareas_id contains a value that is not included in the Priorityareas array or selectedUser.priorityareas_id is null or empty. Check these two cases.

Comment: @MukeshKumar No null values

Comment: I have tested your code in stackblitz and it is working fine. Take a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9sb7u4

Comment: By the way, and if I do so `[ngValue]="selectedUser.priorityareas_id"` then it will give the default value of the selected value which will be the first in the id list Priorityareas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also with this solution.

I have created a demo on  **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/the-default-value-is-displayed-as-empty-in-select?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**. I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

> Component.html

```
<h1>Angular 6 - The default value is displayed as empty in “select”  </h1>

<label for="favcity">
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.priorityarea_id"  name="select" #priorityareas_id='ngModel'>
    <option *ngFor="let Priorityarea of Priorityareas" [value]="Priorityarea.priorityarea_id">
     {{Priorityarea.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</label>

<div>{{selectedUser | json}}</div>
```

> Component.ts

```
selectedUser = {
    priorityarea_id: 2
  }


  Priorityareas = [{
    priorityarea_id: 1,
    name: 'name 1'
  }, {
    priorityarea_id: 2,
    name: 'name 2'
  }, {
    priorityarea_id: 3,
    name: 'name 3'
  }, {
    priorityarea_id: 4,
    name: 'name 4'
  }]
```

Comment: `priorityarea_id `and `priorityareas_id` are two identifiers located in different tables and linked together. And you just ignored him `priorityareas_id`

Comment: Hi @user10223422 I have update URL with  different `priorityarea_id` and `priorityareas_id`

Comment: Okay, I'll mark this decision, but I have the same thing and does not work at all (